# Шаблоны. Перегрузка функции члена и друга класса

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Привожу кусок описания класса. Проблемы возникают сто строчками 1 и 2:

```
template<typename T> class Matrix;
template<typename T> Matrix<T> operator * (T, const Matrix<T> &);
template<typename T> Matrix<T> operator * (const Matrix<T> &, T);

template<typename T>
class Matrix
{
    friend Matrix<T> operator * <T>(const Matrix<T> &, T); //1
    friend Matrix<T> operator * <T>(T, const Matrix<T> &); 
    Matrix<T> operator * (const Matrix<T> &source);        //2
 }
```

Если их объявить в классе в таком порядке, то при написании в main() кода

```
Matrix<int> A, C;
cin >> A;
int d = 5;
C = A * d;
```

Возникает предупреждение

> warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:
>   Matrix operator*(const Matrix&, T) [with T = int]
>   Matrix Matrix::operator*(const Matrix&) [with T = int]|

Если же строки поменять местами, то ошибка возникает на этапе компиляции:

> error: declaration of 'operator*' as non-function|
>   expected ';' at end of member declaration|
>   expected unqualified-id before '<' token|
>   ....

Все остальное(конструкторы, деструкторы, операторы присваивания и т.д. описаны, проверены отдельно и работают.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте написать так:

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix
{
    template<typename U>
    friend Matrix<U> operator * (const Matrix<U> &, U); //1
    template<typename U>
    friend Matrix<U> operator * (U, const Matrix<U> &); 
}
```

Comment: Теперь оно компилируется при любой перестановке этих строк. Но предупреждение осталось.

Comment: Ну, как мне кажется, предупреждение потому, что у вас, наверное, есть конструктор от параметра int. В результате есть вариант использования для умножения на `int` оператора умножения матриц, с преобразованием этого `int` в матрицу. Попробуйте объявить этот конструктор `explicit`.